# Keep html safe from javascript inside div

Tags: javascript, html, security

I'd like to allow external content, including JavaScript, to be loaded into DIV's on my webpage. How can I safe my webpage from the contents (JavaScript/..) requested from other sources?

For example:

```
<body>
     <div id="myPage">

     </div>
     <div id="wrap">
         <div id="ExternalContent">
              <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="somesource"></script>

              <script>
                  var x, y; 
                  //Do something here with x,y;
                  //Potentionally dangerous code
                  alert("hello");
              </script>
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

The content inside div **ExternalContent** should not be able to alter anything in div **myPage**. I am looking for a solution not including iframes or pre-parsed content/pseudo-code. Can a HTML-div be constructed like a "sandbox" impossible to "break out" from?

Comment: May I ask why you want to avoid i-frames?

Comment: @FullyHumanProgrammer - The content is loaded using server-side script from external source, it is not linked on client-side to external source.

Comment: If you load the contents into a div and not an iframe, then your page will always be affected by any css / js that is brought in too.  Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel, it sounds like what you want is exactly what an iframe is for

Comment: @Pete The content comes from external "un-reliable" source, but is not linked to during pageload. The content is from my server but parent content need to be safe from the Child-div. One solution is of cource IFRAME to a locally stored separate page on my server but that is not optimal, actually the content is stored in a server-side database and the logic for what is displayed is decided when the page loads.

Comment: Can an IFRAME be "filled" with content using Javascript? If so, that might be a possible solution for me